# What is the function of the extern "C"?

Tags: c++, oop

its included in the cpp class source file,
it has the following code and from what I am able to search , I havent seen any objects of the derived class declared, Is that why this function is used?

```
extern "C"
{
   derived_class * create_derv_class_resource(dt1 arg1, dt2 arg2)
   {
   return new derived_class(arg1,arg2);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.... Do you ask why this function is defined if nowhere `derived_class` is used???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, what to explain about the "syntax", it's really nothing special.

The semantics of the function is that it creates an object of type `derived_class`, passing on the given parameters to the constructor.

The point of calling this function instead of calling `new` directly might be:

1. It is called from C code, where you cannot create any C++ object directly. The `extern "C"` also indicates this.
2. Someone wants to use the function in a place where a function pointer is required.

Comment: I was skeptical about whether you could actually do this, but it works. [Here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/amullins83/9853816d1609581db169).

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not clear, but if this code works, it's obvious that you have an object named `derived_class` somewhere, and one if its constructors takes a `dt1` and `dt2` parameter.

The function `create_derv_class_resource()` is able to be called from `C` but that seems unlikely here, since `C` would probably not know about the `derived_class` type it needs to parse the prototype.